# MYSQL QUERY triple join + triple count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I need to perform a query but can't make it works...
Any help would be appreciated !
**Performed on MYSQL WORKBENCH**
I got a DB made of 4 tables :

| user | Posts | likes | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| username | id | id | id |
| id | title | userId (foreign key from user.id) | content |
| email | content | postId (foreign key from posts.id) | date |
| password | date |  | userId (foreign key from user.id) |
| image | imageUrl |  | postId (foreign key from posts.id) |
| bio | userId (foreign key from user.id) |  |  |
| createDate |  |  |  |

I want a query that would take specifics datas from USER plus a total count of likes, posts and comments for a specific user and a total result of 0 if no likes / posts / comments exist within this user.
I basically need stats for my user.

My query at the moment give me the good infos for *username / permission / image / bio and createDate* but return me **0 for all counts**.

```
SELECT u.username, u.permission, u.image, u.bio, u.createDate,
COALESCE(P.totalPosts, 0) AS totalPosts,
COALESCE(C.totalComms, 0) AS totalComms,
COALESCE(L.totalLikes, 0) AS totalLikes
FROM user AS u 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalPosts
    FROM posts
) AS P ON P.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalComms
    FROM comments
) AS C ON C.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalLikes
    FROM likes
) AS L ON L.userId = u.id
WHERE u.username = 'Alfred';
```

Thanks for your time  <3 !

Comment: can you share sample content from your tables separately and provide a sample output for the specified inputs?

Comment: Unfortunately for newcomers to SQL, in most RDBMS's this query will fail due to missing `GROUP BY` clauses. Be sure to always enable the [ONLY_FULLGROUP_BY mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) (default of MySQL 8). Head-scratcher to why this is even a mode!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is:

```
GROUP BY userId
```

in all your subqueries:

```
SELECT u.username, u.permission, u.image, u.bio, u.createDate,
       COALESCE(P.totalPosts, 0) AS totalPosts,
       COALESCE(C.totalComms, 0) AS totalComms,
       COALESCE(L.totalLikes, 0) AS totalLikes
FROM user AS u 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalPosts
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY userId
) AS P ON P.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalComms
    FROM comments
    GROUP BY userId
) AS C ON C.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalLikes
    FROM likes
    GROUP BY userId
) AS L ON L.userId = u.id
WHERE u.username = 'Alfred';
```

But, all these subqueries do aggregation for all users and not only for the specific user that you want the results and this is bad for performance.

It would be better if you used correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT u.username, u.permission, u.image, u.bio, u.createDate,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts p WHERE p.userId = u.id) AS totalPosts,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments c WHERE c.userId = u.id) AS totalComms,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes l WHERE l.userId = u.id) AS totalLikes
FROM user AS u
WHERE u.username = 'Alfred';
```

Comment: Curious, why would correlated aggregate queries be *better*? Does the MySQL engine run the aggregations for every row rather than once in derived tables as OP originally has?

Comment: @Parfait in the 1st query each of the 3 subqueries: `SELECT userId, COUNT(*) AS totalPosts FROM posts GROUP BY userId` will aggregate on all the rows of each table. In the 2nd query the 3 correlated subqueries will filter each table and aggregate only on the rows of a specific user.